# Problem in get UserInfo porperty from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, svelte

I'm want to protect a Route in my project throwing people out if they are not logged in. I'm trying to access the `UserInfo` property but I'm getting this error:

> /node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app/index"' has no exported member 'UserInfo'.ts(2694)

my code (svelte):

```js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";
import type firebase from "firebase/app";

const authStore = writable<{
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  user?: firebase.UserInfo;
  firebaseControlled: boolean;
}>({
  isLoggedIn: false,
  firebaseControlled: false,
});

export default {
  subscribe: authStore.subscribe,
  set: authStore.set,
};
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this property: `firebase.UserInfo`. You might want to have a look here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: Nor am I familiar with it. I get from this tutorial: https://phptuts.github.io/svelte-docs/firebase-recipe-site/login/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a late response but I just came across the same issue myself. I couldn't seem to find documentation anywhere for this but here's how I retrieved the type:

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
import type { UserInfo } from 'firebase/auth';

const authStore = writable<{
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
    user: UserInfo | null;
    firebaseControlled: boolean;
}>({
    isLoggedIn: false,
    user: null,
    firebaseControlled: false
});

export default {
    subscribe: authStore.subscribe,
    set: authStore.set
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).